# Routeboxer suddenly doesn't work

Tags: google-maps-api-3, routeboxer

Does anybody know why suddenly Routeboxer does't seem to work?

I have tried to google it and it seems to be  everywhere it doesn't work.

Ex:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.dk/2010/05/search-along-route-made-easy-with.html

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html

Comment: Please show your code and error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Google Code was deprecated according to this:

http://google-opensource.blogspot.com.es/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html?m=1

You can find the libraries exported from the googlecode.com at:

https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library